# SDL2 Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, 18.04, autostart, embedded-system

I have written a code to display some images with golang and SDL2, I have tested the code in the Ubuntu desktop 18.04 and had no issue. 
I wanted to use the code in an embedded configuration, and wanted the OS to run the code automatically on start up, the Ubuntu desktop has a lot of bugs and many times it hangs on the login screen, so I decided to use the Ubuntu server. My problem is that the code in Ubuntu server can't create any window to show the images.
First of all I wanted to know what packages should I install to be able to run SDL, secondly, my monitor and images are 4k, can that also make some trouble?

Answer (score 1):

ok, it seems no one is interested in this question, I found a solution, I installed the xorg package and tried using startx and it solved my problem, If anyone knows a better answer please let me know.

Comment: The fact that you did not have Xorg installed on the machine is information that should be in the question. Combined with this answer from yourself, it makes it clear that your description of the problem is somewhat lacking.

Comment: If I knew about Xorg, I wouldn't even ask this question, I asked this question since I needed help from some experienced people. Now I see it was a very simple question and anyone who had more experience than me could answer this very easily.

Comment: However, you probably had some error messages when you executed your programs? Those are always relevant. Furthermore, there's no real difference between Ubuntu server and Ubuntu desktop, only the selection of packages installed :)

Comment: I was exactly looking for that package, there also no good information in the errors, the errors were just like: can't create renderer or can't create window. I know my question was a noob one, but I'm a noob in Ubuntu :(

Comment: That's fine, we're all new at something :) Focus on how to improve your next question, by including as much information about your problem as possible. [This text](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/how-to-ask-an-effective-question/18584631-7f2b-4f01-88f5-f6660a5943c3) may give some information on asking better questions :)

Comment: Can you describe your solution a little better? I am trying to do the exact same thing